# Centering an UIImage (horizontally or vertically) with programatic constraints UIKit

Tags: ios, uikit, constraints

I am trying to simply center a 5x5 image in a horizontal row in UIKit.

On the left of the view I have a UIView that has its left and top margins attached to the parent view and has intrinsic width and height. It might not exactly fill half of the containing view (so assume its width is arbitrary).

To the right of it (but on the same row) I am trying to put a UIImage that is centered in the blank space to the right of the left object. Meaning it is both centered horizontally and vertically but to the right of the other object.

I really have no clue how to accomplish this although I figure there are both more and less elegant ways to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you set a proper width and height for it set these constraints

```
smallView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
smallView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor, multiplier:1.5).isActive = true
```

Comment: While it does look like it in the diagram the Green object is not guaranteed to be exactly half of the screen so 1.5x the center anchor will not work here.

Comment: either you add a transparent view on the right of the green view and center the smallView according to it  or make a calculation according to the width you set to the greenView

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You'll use a layout guide to define the beginning and end of the horizontal space. Then you'll center your view in the layout guides center. I have included `layoutMarginsGuide` which can be adjusted by setting `container.layoutMargins`.

```
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.backgroundColor = .gray
// Add view to parent ...

let greenView = UIView()
greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
greenView.backgroundColor = .green
containerView.addSubview(greenView)
greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

let horizontalGuide = UILayoutGuide()
containerView.addLayoutGuide(horizontalGuide)
horizontalGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.trailingAnchor, constant: containerView.layoutMargins.left).isActive = true
horizontalGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.backgroundColor = .red
containerView.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```